# What does dev mean in linux commands?

Tags: networking, command-line, wireless

I have been experimenting with Linux recently and I've come across a `dev` argument in some commands when dealing with networks. E.g.:

- ```
  ip link set dev wlan0 up/down
  ```
- ```
  ip link set dev wlan0 address XXX
  ```
- ```
  nmcli dev show wlan0
  ```

The `ip link` commands seem to work without the `dev` argument as well. For `nmcli` I think it lets the system know that I'm talking about a device, and I guess that it has a similar purpose for `ip link`. I'm slightly confused why it's there if it works without it though.

Did `ip` used to need it, but now it's "smarter" or is it something different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the `ip` command `dev` has no meaning. Most likely it was used as an example in the context of having to specify the actual device on which the `ip` command should work (like `wlan0`).

In the `nmcli` command `dev` is a shortcut for specifying the full option name `device` in the command.

Comment: Although the man page doesn't appear to mention it, the built-in help (`ip link help`) gives the syntax of the `link set` command as `ip link set { DEVICE | dev DEVICE | group DEVGROUP } ...` so it looks like `dev` is a kind of "optional keyword" in this context

Answer (score 1):

dev is shorthand for device

in this case, as has been suggested, it may be a placeholder for the device you are looking to perform operations on

when in doubt, I suggest finding via Google a few other examples of the command in question, that normally tells you whether the argument is a placeholder or actually part of the instruction.